# Submit an ng-form if focus is not in the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

```html
 <ng-form name="ctrl.scaleItemForm" ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
      <input type="text"
      ng-model="ctrl.scaleItemPF.tareValue"
      name="tare-val-si">

      <textarea name="sectionLayouts"
      ng-trim="false"
      autocomplete="off"
      autocorrect="off"
      autocapitalize="off"
      spellcheck="false">
      </textarea>

      <button type="submit"
      class="button-save">
      Save
      </button>           
 </ng-form>
```

I am using Angular 1.5.8, In my view, I have a ng-form with ng-submit attached to it so as to trigger submit function on entering key press. I have a textarea inside the ng-form, default behavior when pressing an enter key inside a textarea is a newline, which is happening alongside the submit of the form and I don't want to submit the form if the focus is on texture, instead I need a new line. If replaced with form tag instead of ng-form its working as expected. Is this a bug associated with ng-form or am I doing something wrong

To wrap the question. **Don't want to submit the form on entering key press if the focus is on textarea, otherwise, the form should be submitted.**

Comment: Check this if it is helpful  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if (event && event.target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA'
          && event.keyCode === 13) {
            return undefined;
}
```

Fixed the issue by passing $event to the submit function and checking to see if current input is a textarea and enter key has triggered the submit function returned 'undefined' so as to continue with default behavior of textarea to move cursor to next line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2513) with ng-forms and ng-sumbit.

They are not built to work together. ng-submit is a directive that triggers the submit event of a form tag.
But ng-form is not an HTML5 form its an instance of angular [FormController](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/34axql/what_is_the_difference_between_angulars_ngform/).
This means ng-form with ng-submit does not trigger submit as ng-form does not create an HTML5 form tag. you can see that if you check the HTML in your Application.
***So, to round up, you need to use  instead of  directive.***